# Configure date-time format for JODA in Jackson when deserializing

Tags: java, jackson, jodatime

I am using "Full Data Binding" in Jackson to deserialize a date in a JSON string.

The format these dates are coming is "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy".

I'm using Jackson 1.8 and I cannot figure out how to configure the ObjectMapper so it would deserialize these Strings properly into JODA DateTime objects.

Snippet from the POJO:

```
private DateTime deliveryTime;

@JsonProperty("DeliveryTime")
public void setDeliveryTime(DateTime deliveryTime) {
    this.deliveryTime = deliveryTime;
}

@JsonProperty("DeliveryTime")
public DateTime getDeliveryTime() {
    return deliveryTime;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27102120/695459) for a better solution introduced in Jackson 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to configure ObjectMapper to use specific date/time format is to call `ObjectMapper.setDateFormat(...)` method.

There are some preliminary plans in creating a new Joda datatype Jackson module, as that would make it much easier to add powerful new configuration; current challenge being that Jackson itself should not have hard (static) dependency to external libraries (as much as I like Joda personally!), which limits degree to which lib-specific configurability can work.

Comment: This has now been written!  I've shown some example config at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14185077/125246