# Jackson JavaTimeModule not found even after adding jackson-modules-java8 dependency?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-modules

NOT A DUPLICATE -- I'm trying to follow the solutions given in [Is there a jackson datatype module for JDK8 java.time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384820/is-there-a-jackson-datatype-module-for-jdk8-java-time) (it is the cause of this question, not a duplicate).

I added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-modules-java8</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

But I'm still not able to do this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

The `JavaTimeModule` class is nowhere to be found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check if package added to the classpath when you execute maven you should be able to import the package

Comment: All the answers on the page *you* linked to says to depend on `jackson-datatype-jsr310`. Don't know where you got it, but `jackson-modules-java8` isn't listed *anywhere* in the question or any of the answers. I'm closing this as a duplicate of [your own link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21384820/5221149). Even the [documentation of the `jackson-modules-java8` module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8#usage) you're trying to depend on says that.

Comment: To beginners with java modules (Java 9+), do not forget to add the 'requires com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310' in module-info.java.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you'll be able to register the [`JavaTimeModule`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html) class. See the [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) for details.

Comment: this works, but the actual problem was the `<type>pom</type>` ?!

Comment: @AlexR The `groupId` is wrong as well...