# Spring Boot Cannot Deserialize Object That contanis OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, object, mapper

I'm trying to call a rest endpoint which returns a pojo object which looks like this:

```
public class Process   {
  @JsonProperty("id")
  private String id = null;

  @JsonProperty("processDefinitionId")
  private String processDefinitionId = null;

  @JsonProperty("businessKey")
  private String businessKey = null;

  @JsonProperty("startedAt")
  private OffsetDateTime startedAt = null;

  @JsonProperty("endedAt")
  private OffsetDateTime endedAt = null;

  @JsonProperty("durationInMs")
  private Integer durationInMs = null;

  @JsonProperty("startActivityDefinitionId")
  private String startActivityDefinitionId = null;

  @JsonProperty("endActivityDefinitionId")
  private String endActivityDefinitionId = null;

  @JsonProperty("startUserId")
  private String startUserId = null;

  @JsonProperty("deleteReason")
  private String deleteReason = null;

  //constructors and setters+getters
}
```

Here is the call:

```
ResponseEntity<Process> responseModel = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8062/processes", HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Process.class);
```

The problem is that i've tried a few methods like ignoring the OffsetDateTime properties or trying to change the format of that date but it will throw this error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.threeten.bp.OffsetDateTime` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2019-10-04T13:20:29.315Z')
```

Or it will return null :(
What would be a good solution to solve this?

Comment: And how you put these instances into a database? Maybe it is beter to use Instance instead OffsetDateTime

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384820/is-there-a-jackson-datatype-module-for-jdk8-java-time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error states it cannot construct instance of org.threeten.bp.OffsetDateTime. You need to use

```
java.time.offsetdatetime
```

Then in your model you can format it whatever way you like e.g.

```
@JsonProperty("endedAt") //this line is not needed when it is the same as the instance variable name
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
private OffsetDateTime endedAt;
```

Comment: threeten is a backport for java7, it is obsolete now

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a bean generated by swagger. To solve it I created some serializer and deserializer for date types: org.threeten.bp.LocalDate and org.threeten.bp.OffsetDateTime. And it works well :).

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper serializingObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
    javaTimeModule.addSerializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new OffsetDateTimeSerializer());
    javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new OffsetDateTimeDeserializer());
    javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer());
    javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer());
    objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
    return objectMapper;
}

public static class OffsetDateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<OffsetDateTime> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(OffsetDateTime arg0, JsonGenerator arg1, SerializerProvider arg2) throws IOException {
        arg1.writeString(arg0.toString());
    }
}

public static class OffsetDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<OffsetDateTime> {
    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime deserialize(JsonParser arg0, DeserializationContext arg1) throws IOException {
        return OffsetDateTime.parse(arg0.getText());
    }
}

public static class LocalDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDate> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDate arg0, JsonGenerator arg1, SerializerProvider arg2) throws IOException {
        arg1.writeString(arg0.toString());
    }
}

public static class LocalDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {
    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser arg0, DeserializationContext arg1) throws IOException {
        return LocalDate.parse(arg0.getText());
    }
}
```