# Joda time in Quarkus

Tags: jodatime, quarkus

I am using Quarkus, but it has been obtained the following error:
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Joda date/time type `org.joda.time.DateTime` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda" to enable handling"

Then, I added the dependency in the pom.xml file:

```
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.4</version>
```

But, the error does not disappear. In the resource, I tried to obtain the following request:

```
@GET
public DateTime getTime(){
    return new DateTime(2019, 03, 24, 3,50);
}
```

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: By the way, the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. Its creator Stephen Colebourne went on to lead JSR 310 defining the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later. See [this Questiin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21384820/642706) about Jackson supporting *java.time*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add something like:

```
@Singleton
public class MyCustomizer implements ObjectMapperCustomizer {

    public void customize(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
    }
}
```

in order to make the `ObjectMapper` configured by Quarkus, aware of Joda types