# ZonedDateTime cannot be parsed from JSON, but parses fine with the formatter

Tags: json, datetime, jackson, zoneddatetime

I have this date string coming in through JSON: "29-OCT-21 12.00.00.000000000 AM UTC". I want to save it as a ZonedDateTime data type.

I have the property set in the model as such:

```
  @JsonProperty("createdTs")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a z", with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)
    private ZonedDateTime createdTs;
```

I am getting an error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.ZonedDateTime` from String "29-OCT-21 12.00.00.000000000 AM UTC": Failed to deserialize java.time.ZonedDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '29-OCT-21 12.00.00.000000000 AM UTC' could not be parsed
```

I can't figure out what is wrong. The pattern works just fine in the formatter in test cases, like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive().appendPattern("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a z").toFormatter(
        Locale.getDefault());
    locationPayload.setcreatedTs(ZonedDateTime.parse("29-OCT-21 12.00.00.000000000 AM UTC", formatter));
```

Comment: Not that it answers your question, but why are you using that format? Why not use something more standard?

Comment: Also, have you registered the [`JavaTimeModule`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32202201/634824)?

Comment: That was the only format that I found that worked. What would be a more standard format? Also, how do I register the JavaTimeModule?

Comment: How to register is in the link I gave.  The standard format for the date and time would be ISO 8601 (RFC 3339), such as `2021-10-29T00:00:00Z`.  `Z` means UTC, so if that's the only time zone you need, then you are set.  You also wouldn't need a `ZonedDateTime` but could instead use an `Instant` or an `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: If you actually need to support other time zones, then a `ZonedDateTime` is appropriate, and you would specify the time zone as its IANA identifier, such as `America/New_York` - either following the string (separated by space or in square brackets without a space), or as a separate field.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm looking into using OffsetDateTime instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to the inability of the `JsonFormat` to handle the complex date-time format you have in the JSON string. To resolve this, you can create a custom deserializer for the ZonedDateTime type.

Here's an example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class ZonedDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<ZonedDateTime> {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a z")
            .toFormatter();

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        String dateString = jsonParser.getText();
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, FORMATTER);
    }
}
```

Your property

```
public class Test {

    @JsonProperty("createdTs")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = ZonedDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private ZonedDateTime createdTs;
//Getter & Settere
}
```

Test

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String s = """
                {
                "createdTs": "29-OCT-21 12.00.00.000000000 AM UTC"
                }
                """;

        Test t = JsonMapper.builder().findAndAddModules().build().readValue(s, Test.class);

        System.out.println(t);
    }
```

Output `Test(createdTs=2021-10-29T00:00Z[UTC])`

Try it and let me know