# Jackson's JsonSerializer and thread safety

Tags: java, json, spring, multithreading, jackson-databind

I have a simple `JsonSerializer` in my Spring project:

```
public class JsonDateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {
    private static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(DATE_FORMAT.format(value));
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateTimeSerializer.class)
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

Do I have to take care of thread-safety and make the `DATE_FORMAT` synchronized (as `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread-safe)? I am not sure how exactly `@JsonSerialize` works - does it create just single serialized instance across all threads? Or does it create separate instance for each transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Jackson sees your type for the first time, (depending on the type) it will build a `BeanSerializer` with the appropriate `JsonSerializer`s for each property. This `BeanSerializer` is cached and reused for future serializations of the same `Type`.

As such, a single instance of `JsonDateTimeSerializer` (per type), which will have been registered with the `JsonDateTimeSerializer`, will be reused for all serializations. It must therefore be thread safe if you plan to use the `ObjectMapper` across multiple threads. (You should since the `ObjectMapper` itself is thread safe.)

Answer (score 4):

If `JsonDateTimeSerializer.serialize` might be called from multiple threads, then this use of `SimpleDateFormat` is not safe. The common approach to avoid inefficient synchronization on  `SimpleDateFormat` is explained well in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/817926/641955). Adapting to your use case:

```
public class JsonDateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {

    private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> formatter = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>() {
        @Override
        protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(formatter.get().format(value));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have had that same multithread issue, and when I added the above code, it went away. So I think correct answer is this for the issue.

Comment: Note that `ThreadLocal` may introduce a memory leak; see https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-5164