# json string with multiple types to Map[String, Object]

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have this json string:

```
{
  "startDate" : "2014-12-17T14:31:40Z",
  "name" : "Izek",
  "age" : 12
}
```

When I convert it with Jackson to `Map[String, Object]` the type of `startDate` is `String` how I can tell Jackson to convert it to `DateTime` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it. 
define my own `UntypedObjectDeserializer` and extend `std.UntypedObjectDeserializer` in the `deserialize` method:

```
if (currentToken == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
   if (_stringDeserializer != null) {
      return _stringDeserializer.deserialize(jp, ctxt)
   }
   String text = jp.getText();
   if (dateTimeFormatRegex.match(text) {
      return toDateTimeObject(text);
   } else {
      return text;
   }
}
return super.deserialize(jp, ctxt)

public DateTime toDateTimeObject(String text) {
     dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(text)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to explicitly set the data format in the objectMapper. You could refer [Date format Mapping to JSON Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463049/date-format-mapping-to-json-jackson) for more details. Alternately, you could do it as http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-serialize-javautildate

Comment: This not what I ask. The mapping to POJO is good. The problem is with the Map type

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a custom map deserializer? You can try to parse the date in there. If  not known in advance, you'll probably hit a performance hit here.