# How to convert bootstrap datetimepicker string to java datetime

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, datetime

[image]**angular controller**

```
                $http({
                      method: 'POST',
                      url: '/Eatery/save',
                      contentType:'application/json',
                      dataType:'json',
                      data:resvnCtrl.user
                })
```

**Spring mvc controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public int save(@RequestBody Reservation reservation) {
        System.out.println(reservation.getTime());
        return reservationRepo.save(reservation);   
    }
```

**Java  model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="reservations")
public class Reservation implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String cnf;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;

    @JsonDeserialize(using=CustomJsonDateDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime time;
    private int seats;
    private String note;

    public Reservation() { }

    public Reservation(String cnf, String name, String email, String phone,
            LocalDateTime time, int seats, String note) {
        this.cnf = cnf;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.time = time;
        this.seats = seats;
        this.note = note;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCnf() {
        return cnf;
    }

    public void setCnf(String cnf) {
        this.cnf = cnf;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }


    public LocalDateTime getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(LocalDateTime time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public int getSeats() {
        return seats;
    }

    public void setSeats(int seats) {
        this.seats = seats;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

}
```

**From browser console**

```
email: "kerhb@regerg.e"
name: "kjergk"
note: "wefwef"
phone: "1234567899"
seats: 2
time: "10/23/2015 5:53 PM"
```

**Custom date deserializer**

```
public class CustomJsonDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date>
{
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser,
            DeserializationContext deserializationcontext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        String date = jsonparser.getText();
        try {
            return format.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

}
```

I have a bootstrap datetimepicker on UI and a java REST webservice at the backend. when i send date select, i got "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.". the datetime string which is sent did not map to the java model. can someone spot my error

Comment: Create a network trace from f12 in your browser and show us the Json passed. Looking at the code it seems to be completely different from what reservation needs to contain

Comment: updated code with console data

Comment: No, we need the Json passed in the post call to your server

Comment: i copied from console itself. i added image now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date format Mapping to JSON Jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463049/date-format-mapping-to-json-jackson)

Comment: You need to tell your Json library (assumption: Jackson) how to convert the date. Other choice is to deliver a timestamp. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463049/date-format-mapping-to-json-jackson

Comment: i used custom date deserializer and used that in my model, but still it produced the same error. updated that above

Comment: Good idea ... Did you perhaps forget to take care of the `PM` at the end of the date ? If this is not the root of the problem my last suggestion is to create an endpoint which creates a JSON from a Reservation for you to compare with the values sent by Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Marged` is rigth saying that you didn't cover `AM/PM` in your date pattern. The proper patter would be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a`. Note also that you don't need a custom deserializer for this, can rather use [`@DateTimeFormat`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html)

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a")
private LocalDateTime time;
```