# Jersey JSON Date formatting POJO Mapping

Tags: java, mysql, jersey

I have date stored in mysql db as DATETIME and the value is stored in db as

```
"2016-09-09 15:56:26"
```

I wanted to display in same format, I am using Jersey 1.19 with POJOMapping and I used Date format in pojo, but the value shown in API is as:

```
"createdDt":1473454586000
```

What is the right approach to display correct date format in GET API, should I use String?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12463731/239094