# custom and different json date format

Tags: java, json

I have found how to customize `ObjectMapper` date format in order to let Spring to help to auto serialize/deserialize (serialize when I want to return object to client, deserialize when the request body is json object), but I have lot of DTO with different date format, some might need `yyyy-mm-dd`, some is `dd-mm-yyyy`, one `ObjectMapper` will not work for different required date format, what is the best practice solution for this issue?

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    converters.add(mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
}

MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"));
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);
    mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.setPrettyPrint(true);
    return mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter;
}
```

Comment: Do you have different pojos mapped to DTOs or using same POJO to map different DTOs?

Comment: Erm... In the controller, I only use DTOs, my POJO is database entity. I am not sure what you mean "map"?

Comment: Am talking about pojos mapped in your repository layer of DTOs

Comment: Yes, I have few POJO entity, because my form data or returned data is not the same as the POJO entity, so I created lot of DTO which is almost the same as POJO but some may not same, and DTO contain some validation logic.

Comment: okies, I thought of telling you to make changes in the member variables representing json date fields with `@JsonFormat
      (shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")` annotation. pattern might vary with the incoming json.

Comment: oh, never thought we can use annotation, will annotation overwrite the configuration in `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. It should just override the properties locally applied to that member variable not other properties applied globally

Comment: Sorry, I should say precedence taken not overwrite, for example, my spring global `ObjectMapper` configured to format date as `yyyy-MM-dd` but annotation stated the member variable's date should format as `dd-MM-yyyy`, `ObjectMapper` should take the annotation one right?

Comment: Hmm., I'm not sure of this. Probably you can test this and let me know. I'm just a starter.. :) You seem to be an expert in this area..

Comment: OK thanks for your feedback, at least I know now, there is such annotation and possibly will be one of the solution. Later I will try it out.

Comment: use @JsonFormat - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463049/date-format-mapping-to-json-jackson/27102120#27102120

Comment: @harshavmb yes, I have tried it, the annotation indeed take higher precedence than the global `ObjectMapper` configuration.

Comment: Oh, nice! Please post this as an answer. It helps many. Thanks @GMsoF!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use custom Serializers and handle the different formats within a single Serializer. Here are a few pages that have some info on how to create custom Serializer/Deserializers:

[Create Custom Serializer](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization)

[Create Custom Deserializer](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization)

-- Edit --

From the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.html#setObjectMapper(org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper)) for MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter (some emphasis added):

```
setObjectMapper
public void setObjectMapper(org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper objectMapper)

    Set the ObjectMapper for this view. If not set, a default ObjectMapper is used.

    Setting a custom-configured ObjectMapper is one way to take further control
    of the JSON serialization process. For example, an extended SerializerFactory
    can be configured that provides custom serializers for specific types.
    The other option for refining the serialization process is to use Jackson's
    provided annotations on the types to be serialized, in which case a
    custom-configured ObjectMapper is unnecessary.
```

This means that you do not even need to call `setObjectMapper` if you have Serializers/Deserializers defined by annotations (as described in the links I posted above). For your benefit, here is an example:

**For Serializing**:

*Create a StdSerializer object to handle the type you are interested in*

```
public class ItemSerializer extends StdSerializer<Item> {
    // ...

    @Override
    public void serialize(Item value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) {
        // Write the Item data into the JsonGenerator
    }
}
```

*Define the Serializer for the object via annotations*

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ItemSerializer.class)
public class Item {
    // ...
}
```

**For Deserialization**

*Create a StdDeserializer object to handle the type you are interested in*

```
public class ItemDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Item> { 
    // ... 

    @Override
    public Item deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // Handle the different date formats here!

        return new Item(/*parsed date object*/);
    }
}
```

*Define the Deserializer for the object via annotations*

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = ItemDeserializer.class)
public class Item {
    // ...
}
```