# Failed to parse "Date" from JSON

Tags: java, json, date, jackson, gson

I have the following JSON string in REST response:

```
"09:41:50 CET"
```

For the corresponding POJO mapper class has a Date type for this field. So I've tried Jackson and GSON to map JSON to Java Object, but both failed with the following messages:

```
GSON: java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date ["09:41:50 CET"]: Invalid number: 09:4
```

---

```
Jackson: InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from
                                 String "09:41:50 CET": not a valid representation
```

Sadly I cannot modify in the POJO class the type to string or anything else, because I get those POJO classes from mvn dependency.

Comment: I think you should assign it to XML type `time`...

Comment: And how/where should I do that?

Comment: Just curious, what date you want to be parsed only from the time value?

Comment: You need to set the correct date format. GSON/Jackson is unable to recognise the timezone text "CET".

Comment: Can you modify the REST api to send a full date and time?

Comment: @NINCOMPOOP Yes, but how/where can I do this?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson No because it's and official 3rd party product with a bug.

Comment: @Twi: Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463049/date-format-mapping-to-json-jackson

Comment: You could remap it as String and then  add custom converter on getter for example or if it is JPA entity you could add JPA custom  @Converter on this filed in the result entity. Because if you are using some "custom pojo"  the solution can be not  very beautiful but effective.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    String jsonStr = "{ \"date\" : \"09:41:50 CET\" }";
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").create();
    JsonElement element = gson.fromJson (jsonStr, JsonElement.class);

    OnlyDate date =gson.fromJson(element, new TypeToken<OnlyDate>(){}.getType());

    System.out.println(date.getDate());

}
```

---

My example DTO is:

```
public class OnlyDate implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SerializedName("date")
    private Date date ;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }


}
```

You have to specify the dateFormat of your gson Element

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of rest you have however if you are using spring rest you can do it by implementing custom Converter check the example at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder.

Answer (score 0):

Since Jackson v2.0, you can use @JsonFormat annotation directly on Object members;

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "HH:mm:ss", timezone="CET")
private Date date;
```

Comment: I cannot access the Java DTO object, because it's coming from a mvn dependecy. Therefore I cannot add this.