# POSTMAN is returning date fields with changed values

Tags: json, oracle, java-8, timezone, postman

I am consuming a REST service and I am receiving a JSON with date attributes that do not match what is in my database. I have two fields called "initialDate" and "finalDate". In the database they are like this:

```
07/MAR/19 00:00:00
07/SEP/19 23:59:59
```

The database timezone:

```
select dbtimezone from dual;
+00:00
```

In my object, inside the Java class, the content of the attributes comes as:

```
public class Klass {

 @NotNull
 private Date initialDate; //initialDate.toString() "Thu Mar 07 00:00:00 CLT 2019"

 @NotNull
 private Date finalDate; // finalDate.toString() "Sat Sep 07 23:59:59:9 CLT 2019"

 public Date initialDate() {
    return this.initialDate == null ? null : new Date(initialDate.getTime());
 }

 public void setInitialDate() {
     this.initialDate = initialDate == null ? null : new Date(initialDate.getTime());
 }

 public Date finalDate() {
    return this.finalDate == null ? null : new Date(finalDate.getTime());
 }

 public void setFinalDate() {
    this.finalDate = finalDate == null ? null : new Date(finalDate.getTime());
 }

}
```

However, in my POSTMAN, it returns this:

```
initialDate: "2019-03-07T03:00:00Z",
finalDate: "2019-09-08T02:59:59Z"
```

Why is POSTMAN adding these 3 hours to my service response? I already try to change the timezone of Windows, but there's no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I've found this article that send me to a solution.

[Date format Mapping to JSON Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463049/date-format-mapping-to-json-jackson)

According by the write-up, In my custom class, I set the following attributes:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSZ");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
this.setDateFormat(df)
```

In this ways, I get the result as I'd like:

```
{
  "initialDate" : "2019-03-07T00:00:00.000-0300",
  "finalDate" : "2019-09-07T23:59:59.000-0300"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Postman` does not add anything to `JSON` response from a server. This representation of given date was generated by server and there is a problem. Firstly, we should start from that you should not use `java.util.Date` since you use `Java8`. There is `java.time` package available and you should use it to represent a time.

`toString` method from `Date` class uses default system's time zone to print date and you should not use it. `java.time.LocalDateTime` should work for you.

Probably your backend service uses some libraries to generate `JSON` response. For example, `Jackson`. It's configuration could be wrong this is why you see wrong dates. See below code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class JsonTimeApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        LocalDateTime initialDate = LocalDateTime.of(2019, 3, 7, 0, 0, 0);
        LocalDateTime finalDate = LocalDateTime.of(2019, 9, 7, 23, 59, 59);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        // or mapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-3"));

        mapper.writeValue(System.out, new Period(initialDate, Date.from(finalDate.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC))));
    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
class Period {

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime initialDate;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    private Date finalDate;
}
```

Above code with time zone set to `GMT` prints:

```
{
  "initialDate" : "2019-03-07T00:00:00",
  "finalDate" : "2019-09-07T23:59:59"
}
```

But when we change time zone to `Etc/GMT-3`, it prints:

```
{
  "initialDate" : "2019-03-07T00:00:00",
  "finalDate" : "2019-09-08T02:59:59"
}
```

You should check what is used to generate `JSON` in your case and configure properly time zone. Notice, that for `initialDate` we do not see this behaviour since we used `java.time.LocalDateTime` class instead of `Date`.

Comment: Nice answer ! Your answer always give some insight, good to learn from you! :)